# Suddenly horribly slow performance permanently

Tags: 16.04, performance

I am experiencing extremely slow performance in Ubuntu 16.04 as soon as it is booted. The CPU, RAM and disk usage seem low and normal, like in the past when the problem didn't exist. 
I've been using Ubuntu 14 on my laptop every day for **1.5 years** without problems, until one day this issue came up, without me installing anything or tweaking any settings on the day before. So I completely uninstalled Ubuntu 14 erasing everything, and installed Ubuntu 16. Everything was smooth again for about **12 days**, until the exact same issue came up again (without me doing anything other than web browsing or viewing PDFs)

The slow performance can be noticed as soon as the desktop is loaded. Pretty much everything is slow, but here are some examples:

- Watching Youtube videos in Chrome. The video is terribly laggy, and even if it ever seems to run ok, simply moving the mouse (without even hovering over anything) makes it laggy again.
- Putting the mouse at the bottom of the side launch bar to expand it
- Clicking the dash
- Typing this message
- Switching between Chrome tabs
- Using an IDE

Specifications:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit
- 8 GB RAM
- Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz × 2

The performance is reported as 'horribly slow' in relation to what it used to be on the same system before the problem arose, which was smooth enough.

Any help to pinpoint the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test your HDD, search for bad sectors, test transfer and access time. Check SMART. Wish you luck.